# How to punctuate sentences like "I'm just calling a spade, a spade."

Tags: punctuation, writing, commas

I was browsing Area 51 and I saw this comment:

> I'm just calling a spade, a spade.

I'm never quite sure how to punctuate sentences like these where a phrase is repeated back to back, without any other words to separate them. Not putting punctuation feels weird, but so does adding a comma. Neither intuitively read like I would say them in a conversation.

With a comma, I would pause before reading the second "a spade"; without punctuation, the inflexion in my voice would be off.

So, is "I'm just calling a spade, a spade." properly punctuated?

Comment: By the way - is this a common saying in English? I know it is in Norwegian, but when I see it here in English, it looks strange...

Comment: @awe: It is common.

Comment: @awe. **Cecily Cardew:** When I see a spade, I call it a spade. **Gwendolin Fairfax**: I am glad to say I have never seen a spade. It's obvious our social spheres have been widely different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need the interposing comma. Just say

> I'm just calling a spade a spade.

The Subaru commercials get this awkwardly wrong:

> It's what makes a Subaru, a Subaru.

No comma needed there either.

Compare the idea using two other nouns.

> I'm calling a spade a shovel.

You would never use a comma there. And just because the nouns are the same doesn't change the sentence structurally.

Comment: +1 for Subaru getting it awkwardly wrong. There was another recent marketing campaign that did it wrong too, though I can't remember which.

Comment: I seem to recall that pre-1900-or-so texts used this sort of comma a lot more frequently. Perhaps it's just a style thing that's recently fallen out of favour? Not at all sure how to search for it, though.

Comment: I don't agree with the Subaru comment. After all, it's an ad, and they can say or write whatever they want. Granted, the comma is not at all needed, but I would argue that is there simply for effect. It actually makes the line more powerful and it forces the reader to pause at "Subaru"! I think it's a particularly great line and it would have been completely boring without the comma.

Comment: It's boring with or without the comma, and if it is there just for effect I think the effect is underwhelming. Like most ad slogans. But hey, YMMV. This Ad's For You.

Answer (score 4):

You don't use a comma.  I agree it looks weird, but there is no pause or separation of ideas.

"I'm just calling a spade a spade" is the correct punctuation.

Comment: Robusto beat me to it.