# What is the origin of “call a spade a spade” and does it have racial connotations?

Tags: etymology, slang

Now that we know [how to punctuate the phrase “call a spade a spade”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10933/how-to-punctuate-sentences-like-im-just-calling-a-spade-a-spade) I am curious where it originated and what the original meaning was.

Also, the term “spade” can have negative racial connotations and a friend of mine told me that she thought the phrase did too. I’ve personally never heard it used in a derogatory way, but I figured this was the place to ask.

Comment: This was a good question. Your friend is correct, about the derogatory use cases though. There are numerous examples in English-language film, usually American, 1960's and 1970's. But that doesn't mean the origin of the phrase, nor its intent was originally derogatory, as the answers all indicate.

Comment: If the spade of the playing cards has been interpreted that way, then why not the clover? Should we stop using black ink as well? I will never give into the absurdity that anything black can potentially be used in a racist context. If I stopped using the expression (to call a spade a spade) for that reason, I would be condoning such absurdity. It has been butchered enough by Erasmus as it is, we don't need to slay it any further.

Comment: Oscar Wilde uses the phrase in his novel "The picture of Dorian Grey" (1890) when the character Lord Henry Wooten remarks: "It is a sad truth, but we have lost the faculty of giving lovely names to things. The man who could call a spade a spade should be compelled to use one. It is the only thing he is fit for."

Comment: @AngryBird Clover? What clover?

Comment: I've used this phrase so many times in the past
I said it today with a friend,a business friend and it occurred to me that it could be taken very wrong. He said nothing, but I apologized. A person we were discussing is of color
I was compelled to look up its origins thanks for the work do you do here but I still will discontinue using the phrase I grew up playing lots of cards and I've heard this a hundred times before
Times change

Comment: @tchrist He's referring to the suit of clubs (which looks like a clover), I assume; from a deck of cards.

Comment: For anyone finding this from a search on the internet (I had never heard the phrase before and wasn't sure if someone was trying to be derogatory or not) here's a quick article that goes over some of the history of the phrase and the modern racial connotation: https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/09/19/224183763/is-it-racist-to-call-a-spade-a-spade

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It goes back to [at least 1542](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/call-a-spade-a-spade.html), so I can confidently say there are no racist origins in the expression.

Apparently it first appeared in English in Nicolas Udall's collection of Erasmus's aphorisms - translated in 1542, but ultimately deriving from [Plutarch's Moralia](http://www.attalus.org/info/moralia.html) in the first century AD.

It's really just an observation that forthright honest people use straightforward words. I doubt the fact that "a spade" happens to be the common example has any special significance, though that obviously wouldn't have worked for Shakespeare in the related [rose by any other name](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/305250.html).

Comment: Then there's the extended version: 'He's the sort of person who calls a spade a bloody shovel.'

Answer (score 14):

This is answered fairly clearly by the [etymonline entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=spade) for *spade*:

> spade (1) 
>       "tool for digging," O.E. *spadu*, from P.Gmc. **spadon* [...] from PIE **spe-* "long, flat piece of wood" (cf. Gk. spathe "wooden blade, paddle," [...] To *call a spade a spade* "use blunt language" (1540s) translates a Greek proverb (known to Lucian), *ten skaphen skaphen legein* "to call a bowl a bowl," but Erasmus mistook Gk. *skaphe* "trough, bowl" for a derivative of the stem of *skaptein* "to dig," and the mistake has stuck.

The item before that in etymonline mentions

> spade (2) ... Derogatory meaning "black person" is 1928, from the color of the playing card symbol,

an unrelated meaning.

Answer (score 6):

The origin of the phrase doesn't have any racial connotations (as jwpat7 and FumbleFingers showed), but you should be careful how you use it because of the derogatory meaning of the word *spade*.

In some situations it would be clear that only the original meaning was intended, but in other situations it might be misinterpreted as wordplay on both expressions.

Comment: I understand the urge to avoid insensitivity, but I'd prefer to simply use the phrase as (innocently) intended. Taking evasive action might give the racially-inflammatory slang too much credence, IMHO.

Comment: @CJM: Yes, please use this phrase where appropriate, only avoid it in situations where the racial association already exists. Dont take my answer as niggardly trying to spook you into never using it. ;)

Comment: @CJM You can prefer to use the phrase as (innocently) intended. But that doesn't mean it will be interpreted as intended. Guffa makes a good point. But on the other hand, you weren't the one who asked the question originally, so I shouldn't even be chiming in here.

Comment: Shall we change the name of the gardening tool, as well?

Comment: @Guffa - Of course, I agree that common sense should prevail - if the context is such that someone might think you were being flippant or insensitive, you would choose different words.

Comment: @FeralOink - While in the UK, legally [racial] offence is often measured by the receiver rather than intender, I don't agree with it. So as Guffa says, providing the context is not unsuitable, use the phrase as originally intended, thus removing some of the potency of the offensive alternative use.

Comment: @CJM I like that perspective! It is constructive, diluting the potency of the offensive alternative use. That is a good way of looking at it.