# Proper punctuation for the statement "That is what makes you you."

Tags: punctuation

What would be the proper punctuation for the statement "That is what makes you you."?

Comment: What does your research say that reference works say, and what more do you need to know?  How is it different from how you would punctuate "Combustion is what makes campfires hot?"

Comment: In my general experience, this sentence is spoken with a pause between the two "you"s, which to me would imply a comma, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: None, other than what it already has.

Comment: "this sentence is spoken with a pause between the two *you*s" -- not a pause, the second *you* is emphasized so it might seem like a pause. HTH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to punctuate sentences like "I'm just calling a spade, a spade."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10933/how-to-punctuate-sentences-like-im-just-calling-a-spade-a-spade)

Answer (score -3):

Hmm... Normally, I would immediately go

> That is, what makes you you.

I'm from Germany and in some instances, punctuation works the same, this included, I think.

However, I've also seen people completely disregard any punctuation. So I assume

> That is what makes you you.

works as well.

Comment: German writing is much more generous with commas than English. Punctuated like your first example makes it read in English like you're saying 'id est, what makes you you'