# That’s what makes Tony Tony

Tags: punctuation

In each below, should there be an intervening comma between the two repeated words?

That’s what makes Tony Tony. (what makes Tony who he is.)
That’s what makes her her. (Same logic.)
That’s what makes him him. (Same logic.)

Thanks.

Comment: If you include a comma (which just reflects a pause in speech), ***That's what makes Tony, Tony*** would be an utterance ***addressed*** to Tony (though you'd have thought at least *Tony* would know what makes him like he is, so it's an unlikely thing to say to him! :) But modeled after ***Come here, you!***, I'd have to say that ***That's what makes you you, you!*** is at least *theoretically* "grammatical".

Comment: If I were marking an A-level essay, I'd not penalise either version. I know there are rules trying to standardise all usages of commas, but in spite of attempts to arrogate here, I'd accept both counter-arguments " << Tony Tony >> looks silly and is garden-pathy" and " << Tony, Tony >> here looks like it's a vocative" (surely context will disallow this reading). Myself? Some days, I'd use an ellipsis; other days, I'd use << That’s what makes Tony _Tony_. >>.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've upvoted both you and Fumble, but I think my approach would be *That's what makes Tony "Tony"*.

Comment: @WS2 Wouldn't you consider the quotes too 'scary' (ie a hint that Tony has some non-standard characteristics)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not really. To me the name in quotes is saying "the personality of Tony", as opposed  to the identity which is Tony. Certainly one is using the name in two different senses, which I believes needs to be reflected in some way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you have any view about putting the second Tony in quotes?

Comment: Please don't discuss questions in comments. Please post answers.

Comment: Like this?

That’s what makes Tony “Tony.” 

That’s what makes him “him.” 

That’s what makes her “her.” 

Why does the second entry get quotes in each and not the first entry? Just curious.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I don't know about the others, but I voted to ***close*** the question. Are you saying my comment here is "unwanted" even in circumstances like that?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I think the broadening is interesting, novel and non-trivial. Should someone widen the question, or write another? Neither seems too respectful; the question as it stands has merits.

Comment: Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/450059/191178

Comment: There is definitely **some** intonation involved in repeated NPs in this construction. In speech it's not a problem. In writing, of course, it is, since writing doesn't have the chops to do intonations. Comma normally refers to a Mid-High-Low-Mid intonation sequence, and that's not what makes this construction this construction. The first NP is higher in pitch than the second, but a comma isn't gonna make anybody hear that sequence. So, commas are out. But there isn't any adequate punctuation mark.

Comment: No need for a comma. Curiosity is what makes a cat a cat. Loyalty is what makes a dog a dog.

Comment: Commas used purely as an aid to the eye in reading a text Chicago Manual of Style (13th ed) says in section 5.56: 'For ease of reading, it is sometimes desirable to separate two identical or closely similar words with a comma, even though the sense or grammatical construction does not require such separation. ' But this is a duplicate, so I'll not give this as an answer. In any case, I'd use the options I've already mentioned, not the comma.

Answer (score 2):

If these two last words at the end of the sentence were different, you wouldn't put a comma in:

> That's what makes a house a home.

So you shouldn't put a comma in even if they're identical.

Comment: Argument from analogy. Always questionable, especially in English. I believe CMOS licenses the use of a comma in situations where strange juxtapositions look even stranger without one. Argument from authority (unless my memory's becoming worse; another year _has_ just gone by).

Comment: _Gorrit._  << _Commas used purely as an aid to the eye in reading a text_

Chicago Manual of Style (13th ed) says in section 5.56:

_For ease of reading, it is sometimes desirable to separate two identical or closely similar words with a comma, even though the sense or grammatical construction does not require such separation._

[Making the unmissable, unmissable.]

Answer (score 1):

Should there be an intervening comma? Yes.

> That’s what makes Tony, Tony.

The *Chicago Manual of Style* (13th ed) says:

> For ease of reading, it is sometimes desirable to separate two identical or closely similar words with a comma, even though the sense or grammatical construction does not require such separation: 
>   "Let us march in, in twos."
>   "Whatever is, is good."
>   *But:* "He gave his life that that cause might prevail."
>   (Source: CMOS, Paragraph 5.56)

Note that the "sense or grammatical construction does not require such separation"; however, the comma provides a small indicator to the reader that there should be a short break (and possibly intonation change) after the first "Tony."

Comment: I don't actually think the comma makes the OP's sentence any easier to read, although it certainly does for the examples that CMOS gives.

Answer (score 1):

Either is acceptable in published writing.

I tested this with an analogous set of examples to your own:

> (1) That's what makes you you
>
> (2) That's what makes you, you

Among the books conforming to (1) are *[Thankless in Death](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thankless_in_Death/Ra6soCJYiSoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22That%27s%20what%20makes%20you%20you%22&pg=PA173&printsec=frontcover)* by J.D. Robb, *[But Don't Call Me White](https://www.google.com/books/edition/But_Don_t_Call_Me_White/ge_NxDNHJ6kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22That%27s%20what%20makes%20you%20you%22&pg=PA135&printsec=frontcover)* by Silvia Bettez, and *[The Paris Affair](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Paris_Affair/pjBudTWlfBMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22That%27s%20what%20makes%20you%20you%22&pg=PT145&printsec=frontcover)* by Teresa Grant.

Meanwhile, the books conforming to (2) include *[Vows](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Vows/Wk5EHClaae0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22That%27s%20what%20makes%20you%20you%22&pg=PA235&printsec=frontcover)* by John Porec and *[The Diary of Margaret Evans](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Diary_of_Margaret_Evans/X6eaAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22That%27s%20what%20makes%20you%20you%22&pg=PA99&printsec=frontcover)* by Alyanna Tate.

So in practice the usage is up to the editor and writer.

---

*[The Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec055.html)* (17th edition; may be paywalled) also allows for both. Paragraph 6.55 leaves the clarification up to the editor:

> For ease of reading and subject to editorial discretion, two words that are spelled alike but have different functions may be separated by a comma if such clarification seems desirable.
>
> > Let us march in, in twos.
> >
> > Whatever is, is good.
>
> but
>
> > “It depends on what *means* means.”

Their use of italics suggests an emphatic alternative:

> That's what makes Tony *Tony*.